# Pure python range implementation

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, interval

I implemented class `Range` as an equivalent to Python built-in `range` for practicing purposes. No features were added. Hope it mimics all aspects of `range` behavior, but maybe you can point out something I forgot. Also I tried to make the code efficient, that's why `Range` doesn't inherit from `collections.abc.Sequence` and doesn't use any of it's not abstract methods. All feedback on how to improve the code is welcome!

pyrange.py

```
"""
Pure Python implementation of built-in range
"""


import math
import collections.abc
import numbers


def interpret_as_integer(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, '__index__'):
        return obj.__index__()
    raise TypeError(
        '\'{}\' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'.format(
            type(obj).__name__
        )
    )


def adjust_indices(length, start, stop, step):
    if step is None:
        step = 1
    else:
        step = interpret_as_integer(step)

    if start is None:
        start = length - 1 if step < 0 else 0
    else:
        start = interpret_as_integer(start)
        if start < 0:
            start += length
            if start < 0:
                start = -1 if step < 0 else 0
        elif start >= length:
            start = length - 1 if step < 0 else length

    if stop is None:
        stop = -1 if step < 0 else length
    else:
        stop = interpret_as_integer(stop)
        if stop < 0:
            stop += length
            if stop < 0:
                stop = -1 if step < 0 else 0
        elif stop >= length:
            stop = length - 1 if step < 0 else length

    return start, stop, step


class Range:
    """
    Range(stop) -> Range object
    Range(start, stop[, step]) -> Range object

    Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
    to stop (exclusive) by step. Range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
    start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  Range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
    These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
    When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
    """

    __slots__ = ('start', 'stop', 'step', '_len')

    def __init__(self, start, stop=None, step=1):
        if stop is None:
            start, stop = 0, start
        self.start, self.stop, self.step = (
            interpret_as_integer(obj) for obj in (start, stop, step)
        )
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError('Range() arg 3 must not be zero')
        step_sign = int(math.copysign(1, self.step))
        self._len = max(
            1 + (self.stop - self.start - step_sign) // self.step, 0
        )

    def __contains__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, numbers.Integral):
            return self._index(value) != -1
        return any(n == value for n in self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Range):
            return False
        if self._len != len(other):
            return False
        if self._len == 0:
            return True
        if self.start != other.start:
            return False
        if self[-1] == other[-1]:
            return True
        return False

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            start, stop, step = adjust_indices(
                self._len, index.start, index.stop, index.step
            )
            return Range(
                self.start + self.step * start,
                self.start + self.step * stop,
                self.step * step
            )
        index = interpret_as_integer(index)
        if index < 0:
            index += self._len
        if not 0 <= index < self._len:
            raise IndexError('Range object index out of Range')
        return self.start + self.step * index

    def __hash__(self):
        if self._len == 0:
            return id(Range)
        return hash((self._len, self.start, self[-1]))

    def __iter__(self):
        value = self.start
        if self.step > 0:
            while value < self.stop:
                yield value
                value += self.step
        else:
            while value > self.stop:
                yield value
                value += self.step

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.step == 1:
            return 'Range({}, {})'.format(self.start, self.stop)
        return 'Range({}, {}, {})'.format(self.start, self.stop, self.step)

    def __reversed__(self):
        return iter(self[::-1])

    def _index(self, value):
        index_mul_step = value - self.start
        if index_mul_step % self.step:
            return -1
        index = index_mul_step // self.step
        if 0 <= index < self._len:
            return index
        return -1

    def count(self, value):
        """
        Rangeobject.count(value) -> integer
        Return number of occurrences of value.
        """
        return sum(1 for n in self if n == value)

    def index(self, value, start=0, stop=None):
        """
        Rangeobject.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer
        Return index of value.
        Raise ValueError if the value is not present.
        """
        if start < 0:
            start = max(self._len + start, 0)
        if stop is None:
            stop = self._len
        if stop < 0:
            stop += self._len

        if isinstance(value, numbers.Integral):
            index = self._index(value)
            if start <= index < stop:
                return index
            raise ValueError('{} is not in Range'.format(value))

        i = start
        n = self.start + self.step * i
        while i < stop:
            if n == value:
                return i
            i += 1
            n += self.step
        raise ValueError('{} is not in Range'.format(value))


collections.abc.Sequence.register(Range)
```

test_pyrange.py

```
# pylint: disable = too-few-public-methods

import itertools

from pyrange import Range


class Equal:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True


class Indexable:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __index__(self):
        return self.n


def test_basic():
    small_builtin_range = range(10)
    small_my_range = Range(10)
    equal = Equal()
    assert small_builtin_range.count(equal) == small_my_range.count(equal) == 10
    assert small_my_range.index(equal) == small_my_range.index(equal) == 0

    big_my_range = Range(0, 10 ** 20, 10 ** 5)
    assert 10 ** 15 in big_my_range
    assert big_my_range[Indexable(10 ** 3)] == 10 ** 8
    assert big_my_range[
        Indexable(10 ** 3):Indexable(10 ** 6):Indexable(10 ** 2)
    ] == Range(10 ** 8, 10 ** 11, 10 ** 7)


def test_slicing():
    for start, stop, step in itertools.product(range(-3, 3), repeat=3):
        if step == 0:
            continue
        builtin_range = range(start, stop, step)
        my_range = Range(start, stop, step)
        for slice_start, slice_stop, slice_step in itertools.product(
                list(range(-3, 3)) + [None], repeat=3
        ):
            if slice_step == 0:
                continue
            slc = slice(slice_start, slice_stop, slice_step)
            builtin_range_slice = builtin_range[slc]
            my_range_slice = my_range[slc]
            for name in ('start', 'stop', 'step'):
                assert (
                    getattr(builtin_range_slice, name) ==
                    getattr(my_range_slice, name)
                ), (start, stop, step, slice_start, slice_stop, slice_step)


def test_eq_and_hash():
    for start, stop, step in itertools.product(range(-3, 3), repeat=3):
        if step == 0:
            continue
        builtin_range = range(start, stop, step)
        my_range = Range(start, stop, step)
        for start_2, stop_2, step_2 in itertools.product(
                range(-3, 3), repeat=3
        ):
            if step_2 == 0:
                continue
            builtin_range_2 = range(start_2, stop_2, step_2)
            my_range_2 = Range(start_2, stop_2, step_2)
            if builtin_range == builtin_range_2:
                assert my_range == my_range_2, (
                    start, stop, step, start_2, stop_2, step_2
                )
                assert hash(my_range) == hash(my_range_2), (
                    start, stop, step, start_2, stop_2, step_2
                )
```

Comment: Your constructor is `__init__(start, stop=None, step=1)`. Shouldn't `start` be optional and `stop` positional? `range(3)` means `[0, 1, 2]`, not `[3, 4, 5, ...]`.

Comment: @JackM in case of `Range(3)` there are lines `if stop is None: start, stop = 0, start`.

Comment: Your `__contains__` method iterates through the range, but it should be able to determine this purely from the start/stop/step, at least in the case of `int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not mimic all aspects of `range`.  The `range` object is immutable:

```
>>> r = range(1,5,2)
>>> r.start
1
>>> r.start = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  module __main__ line 130
    traceback.print_exc()
  module <module> line 1
    r.start = 3
AttributeError: readonly attribute
>>>
```

Yours is not.  But you might be able to fix that by inheriting from `collections.namedtuple`.

Comment: Good point about immutability. However I don't think that inhertiting from `collections.namedtuple` is the best idea. Do you know another alternatives?

Comment: The are hacks to make objects immutable, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48055480/3690024) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4828108/3690024), but why are you opposed to inheriting from `namedtuple`?

Comment: Because logically `Range` has nothing common with `namedtuple` or `tuple`. `range_obj[0] == range_obj.start` but `range_obj[1] != range_obj.stop` in many cases and `range_obj[2] != range_obj.step` in many cases.

Comment: As I see, hacking `__setattr__` is the best way.

Comment: Hmm.  It seems I can’t subclass a `namedtuple` and overload the `__getitem__` method to a different behaviour.  How ... exceptional.  Well, you’ve got the `__setattr__` hack, so you can make your `Range` immutable that way.